# How to use expression to simulate mathematical expression?

Tags: c#, expression

below is my code fragment:

```
        ConstantExpression constant1 = Expression.Constant(5);
        ConstantExpression constant2 = Expression.Constant(5.3);
        Expression expr = Expression.Multiply(constant1, constant2);
        var compiled = Expression.Lambda<Func<double>>(expr).Compile();
        Console.WriteLine(compiled.Invoke());
        Console.WriteLine();
```

System raise exception at `Expression expr = Expression.Multiply(constant1, constant2);`
the error message is there is no binary operator Multiply between “System.Int32” and “System.Double”. I change the multiply to add and div the error message is same.

How to use expression to  simulate mathematical expression?

ps: I won't to use expression like `ConstantExpression constant1 = Expression.Constant(5.0);`. Because if I write such code like below:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("5*5.3={0}",5 * 5.3));
```

It's OK, is there any way to simulate such mathematical expression?

Comment: "ps: I won't to use expression like `ConstantExpression constant1 = Expression.Constant(5.0);`" - Why not?

Comment: One of options is to wrap the int with the conversion operator. This approach could potentially handle more cases `var constant1 = Expression.Convert( Expression.Constant(5), typeof( double ) );`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using

```
ConstantExpression constant1 = Expression.Constant(5.0);
```

you can use:

```
ConstantExpression constant1 = Expression.Constant(5d);
```